# Tag search in org mode delivers empty list although searched Tag exists

Tags: org-mode, search, tags

I have an .org file and some headlines have the tag Contact attached to them yet searching for tags (C-c a m) and entering Contact delivers nothing (see attached screenshot). What do I do wrong?
Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: You can restrict the agenda to the current buffer using key `<`.  Have the cursor in the buffer of interest.  Then do `C-c a < m Contact RET`.

Answer (score 1):

KO, I think that C-c a m works only in Agenda files and the one I searched is not a dedicated agenda file. Anyway (org-match-sparse-tree) which should do the trick delivers more than I want i.e. every Headline no matter which tag it has. Puzzled.